# Og: Image and Facebook Link thumbnails

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a problem with the og:image tag. I followed the instructions on SO about implementing the tag, which was very straight forward. It works great when someone like's the page. There is now a problem though, that when I post the link into a message I am composing on facebook, it does not show any thumbnail.

Here's my site: http://www.sunlitehardware.com.au/

So check this.

Okay jump onto facebook, and create a private message to one of your friends. 
Paste in this link: http://www.sunlitehardware.com.au/blog/Power-Tools-Save-Your-Energy
Watch the thumbnail box below the post generate, and pull in some data. You'll notice it has a title, a link but no image.

The head of that particular link looks like this:

```
 <head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://www.sunlitehardware.com.au/site/assets/template/images/favicon.ico" />

    <meta property="og:title" content="Power Tools - Save Your Energy" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.sunlitehardware.com.au/site/assets/media/Bosch-1590EVSK-6.jpg"/>  

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content=" Sunlite Hardware stock a massive range of tools for all your hardware needs in Sydney City & Bondi Junction." />
    <meta name="keywords" content=",hardware, store, city, power tools, llight bulbs, paint, sydney, bondi junction" />
    <meta name="verify-v1" content="Ow6TX6iHLufi9DAwV6mWquC9SEW4Les+o/wz29uUdeY=" />
```

If you take a look, the link to the og:image link, you can see the link points here: 
http://www.sunlitehardware.com.au/site/assets/media/Bosch-1590EVSK-6.jpg

If you were to click that, you should be able to see the image, i know I can, so the link is working.

Seems like for some reason facebook is ignoring it .. 
Take a look at the facebook lint page here: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sunlitehardware.com.au%2Fblog%2FPower-Tools-Save-Your-Energy

It has the thumbnail there. It just won't work when making posts. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the og:image, try using an image that's closer to 50x50 (yours is roughly 1200x1200).

Comment: Hey mate, great idea. I've tried it though and it makes no difference. For example, if you look at the root page, it has an image that is only 100x100. This has the same issue as the page with 1200x1200. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Take a look at the fields you're missing. You're missing og:title, og:url etc.

Answer (score 2):

The [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) is a handy way of checking your links and usually warns you of the problems with your OG tags.